# Нужно выбрать способ оплаты с помощью радио кнопок и кнопкой отправки формы

Tags: html

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" value="https://qiwi.com" name="r1">
    <input type="radio" value="https://paypal.com" name="r1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Есть данная форма, где несколько радио кнопок и в каждой ссылка на оплату нужным способом. Хочу узнать как сделать переход на ссылку с нужным способом после нажатия кнопки сабмит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```js
const submit = document.querySelector('[type="submit"]')

submit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const radio = document.querySelector('input[name=r1]:checked')

  if (radio) {
    window.location.href = radio.value
  } else {
    console.log('Кнопка не выбрана')
  }
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" value="https://qiwi.com" name="r1">
  <input type="radio" value="https://paypal.com" name="r1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```